# Automatically add column to data table according to week

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2

I'm working on a table that shows data per week. How can I automatically add a column after a week has passed by and show its data from the database? Thank you in advance.

## MVC2

## Jquery

Comment: Could you explain in detail what you mean by, "passed", and perhaps show the necessary code so we can further help you?

Comment: Honestly, I'm a newbie and I have no idea how to start. I'm hoping to get ideas from people out here how to do this. What I mean by a "week passed by" is a week is gone and were going to a new week. Thanks :)

Comment: Have you used ASP.NET or MVC before?

Comment: Yes.. but Im still a newbie.

Answer (score 0):

If you meant that for every week, in real-life and not in the database, you would update the table, this can be done via JavaScript just by using `new Date()` and extracting the necessary information to find out how many weeks have passed and how many columns you need to add to your table.
You can use jQuery's Ajax methods to fetch info from databases as well: [w3schools - jQuery Ajax Methods](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_ajax.asp)
It should work for PHP (MySQL) Databases and ASP related Databases!

Hope that helps!